# Trouble with the onmouseover function

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting the onmouseover function working in jquery. What I want to do is when you hover over the word "here" the image pops up. The plugin is working fine just don't know how to handle the onmouseover or hover event?

HOVER ISNT WORKING IN MY CODE

```
('a.lightbox').hover(function(){
  $('a.lightbox').lightBox();     
});

 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="outer">
    <a href="image1.jpg" class="lightbox">here</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This doesnt work either.....

```
 $('a.lightbox').hover(function() {
    $(this).lightBox();
    });
```

Isn't there something where I can simply hover over a word and an image pops up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the $. Try this

```
$('a.lightbox').hover(function(){
  $('a.lightbox').lightBox();     
});
```

Also, you can use `$(this).lightBox();` instead for the second line.

Here's an example: http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2

Comment: Well the `.hover` works, you can even check the documentation (the link I posted). It's probably either your selector or the `.lightBox()`. I don't know much about how the lightbox works, but andypaxo noted that the way you're using it might be wrong. Try this: open up the Error Console (Firefox) or double click on the "Error" message in the statusbar (IE) or whatever your browser's equivalent is and check to see which line is causing the error and why.

Comment: Checked the docs for lightbox, looks like as long as you have the javascripts linked and an <a> has the class "lightbox", the second line should work. Also, if the error console (or w/e) shows no errors, put something like `alert('hi');` inside the hover function to see if it's actually being run. If not, then there's probably something wrong with your selector.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you missed the '$' sign of jQuery

see for demo http://jsfiddle.net/Vjhz3/7/

Comment: I dont wanna click, rather hover....I have it working clicking too but I need to hover over the word and display an image. Is that possible?

Comment: @Nick LaMarca: what do you mean? there won't be real "hover effect" when using LightBox beacuse of the background. this sort of works but you will need to click the image again to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here...

1. You want to use `$('a.lightbox')` on the first line, not `('a.lightbox')`
2. I don't think that's the right way to use lightbox, have a look at the docs

Answer (score 0):

In addition to missing the $ sign, this code will not work because it will open all elements with the selector a.lightbox, not just the one hovered on, try this:

```
$('a.lightbox').hover(function(){
  $(this).lightBox();     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue @mahesh found, you should also not use the `hover` function; when using `hover` with one function, your function is used when the mouse both enters and leaves the element.  Use the `mouseenter` or `mouseover` events instead.